# How to use type definition from d.ts file as doctype in js file?

Tags: typescript, webpack, doctype

I want to use definition of webpack Configuration object in my webpack.config.js file to get IDE hints. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for it is the following:

```
/**
 * @param {import('webpack').Configuration} config
 */
module.exports = function override(config) {
  ...
```